# Do I need to use a plural proper noun?

Tags: grammar, british-english

For example if i want to say

> all children are albert einstein

Is it correct or should this be

> all children are albert einsteins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be outrageous if you say "*all children are Albert Einstein*". Not because of the plural existence of children, but the fact that there was only one Albert Einstein.

In modern English, '***[Einstein](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Einstein)***' has been adopted as a noun, which means:

> *someone who has exceptional intellectual ability and originality*

Having said so, you could say that "**All children are Einsteins**".

You should omit his first name, as the noun is defined only for his surname.

Also, since '*children*' is the plural form of the noun '*child*', you must address them as individual '*Einsteins*', and not collectively call them as '*Einstein*'

Comment: Then why not " all children are Albert Einsteins"

Comment: There isn't a rule that you MUST omit his first name. It's advisable to do so because, **1.** Everybody know you're talking about Albert Einstein. So you need not use his first name. It is obvious. **2.** '_Albert Einstein_' is a person's name, but '_Einstein_' is a noun, which, although not extensively used, can be used to emphasis the intelligence of a person. The so-called noun is '_Einstein_', and not his full name.